# VB.NET: Sending Multiple Arguments To a Background Worker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, arguments, backgroundworker, argument-passing

I am trying to use a BackgroundWorker to perform tasks on a separate thread.

I am able to pass a single argument to the BackgroundWorker as below:

**Send argument to BackgroundWorker:**

```
Private Sub btnPerformTasks_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPerformTasks.Click

    Dim strMyArgument as String = "Test"
    BW1.RunWorkerAsync(strMyArgument)

End Sub
```

**Retrieve argument inside BackgroundWorker:**

```
Private Sub BW1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BW1.DoWork
    Dim strMyValue As String
    strMyValue = e.Argument  'Test
End Sub
```

There are only 2 overloaded methods for `RunWorkerAsync()`. One that takes no arguments and one that takes one argument.

I want to know:

1. How can I pass multiple values to `BW1.RunWorkerAsync()`
2. How can I retrieve these multiple values from inside `BW1_DoWork`

Comment: One argument is enough to pass an object with as many properties as you need.  Write a little helper class.  Or use a lambda expression.

Comment: @HansPassant I believe the answer that pacane provided is the helper class method. Could you show how to use a lambda expression to achieve this?

Comment: @HansPassant The question is clearly stated above. I can accomplish what is needed for the question using the class method as answered by pacane. I only wanted to know if by using a lambda expression, i could do the same thing more efficiently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can wrap your arguments in an object and then pass that object to the worker.

To retrieve it, you can just cast `e` in the DoWork to your custom type.

here's an example:

```
' Define a class named WorkerArgs with all the values you want to pass to the worker.
Public Class WorkerArgs
    Public Something As String
    Public SomethingElse As String
End Class

Dim myWrapper As WorkerArgs = New WorkerArgs()
' Fill myWrapper with the values you want to pass

BW1.RunWorkerAsync(myWrapper)

' Retrieve the values
Private Sub bgw1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        ' Access variables through e
        Dim args As WorkerArgs = e.Argument
        ' Do something with args
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: @slayernoah There you go

Comment: Realized that `Dim args As WorkerArgs = e.Argument` is not necessary in the example above. Looks like I can get the passed values using `e.Argument.Something` and `e.Argument.SomethingElse`.